# Calling Volley from another class

Tags: java, android, object

I have an Activity class with quite a lot web services running and want to make my program more "object oriented",so it can be maintainable and easy to read . For example look at the following example.

```
public class Welcome extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);





    buildFitnessClient();

    showUser(username,password);

}

private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))

            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.  What to do?
                            // Look at some data!!

                            //showUser(username,password);

                            new InsertAndVerifyDataTask().execute();


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                // Show the localized error dialog
                                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                        Welcome.this, 0).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
                            // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
                            // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
                            if (!authInProgress) {
                                try {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                    authInProgress = true;
                                    result.startResolutionForResult(Welcome.this,
                                            REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,
                                            "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect to the Fitness API
    Log.i(TAG, "Connecting...");

    mClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mClient.isConnected()) {
        mClient.disconnect();
        //showUser(username,password);


    }

}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //showUser(username,password);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
        authInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mClient.isConnecting() && !mClient.isConnected()) {
                mClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
 private void showUser(final String username, final String password) {
    HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    location = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
    final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParams.put("username", username);

    postParams.put("password", password);

    Response.Listener<JSONObject>  listener;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(postParams);

    //{"password":"larissa","username":"samsungtest"}
    //{"password":"larissa","username":"theo81developer@gmail.com"}
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.URL_USER_CHECK, jsonObject,

            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   // {"message":"User Information found.","user":{"username":"samsungtest","league_points":null,"team_id":"189","location":"GB","latest_steps":"0","user_type":"LEADER","nickname":"samsungtest"},"status":"success"}
                   //{"message":"User Information found.","user":{"username":"theo81developer@gmail.com","league_points":null,"team_id":"228","location":"GB","latest_steps":"5033","user_type":"LEADER","nickname":"Samsung User"},"status":"success"}

                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                    try {
                        if (response.getString("status").equals("success")){

                            userTable(response);

                            localRanking(username,password,location);
                            globalRanking(username,password);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

}
```

How can I make it work if I was calling buildFitnessClient() and showUser(...) from another class? I tried some different ways like instastiating a Class called Fitness with buildFitnessClient() method inside,but I am getting null pointer exception on View objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your methods as static so that you can call them from another class or activity and simply pass the required parameters that it may need (such as context, views, etc). And simply use them as something like *Fitness.buildFitnessClient( < variables > )*

OR

Implement a **singleton** where you can set variables to be used by your methods and do what you want to do. This, however, is much more complex (*at least for me*)

** **Just be careful with memory leaks** **

Comment: Thanks for that. Also I don't have any memory leaks so I don't have any problems.